# Remove child entities from copy, new parent, of already existing entity, parent

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to remove children from the newly cloned parent entity. So that new entity does not have all the children from the original parent but only the other properties

Parent Entity

```
public class AlertDetail {

/**   Some properties **/

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alertDetail", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private final Set<AlertReceiverDetail> receiverDetails = new HashSet<>();


  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<AlertDataEventMetadata> dataEventMetadata = new HashSet<>();
}
```

When I try to detach and save the entity after making required changes through

By clearing the set after detaching the original entity

```
entityManager.detach(alertDetail);
alertdetail.getReceiverDetails().clear();
dao.save(alertDetail);
```

I am getting transaction not present error
`failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:`
and that's understandable,
but the thing is I doesn't want it to be eagerly loaded as that list is large

Answer (score 0):

Replace the collection with a new instance instead of clearing it by using `alertdetail.setReceiverDetails(new HashSet<>());`

Comment: I had tried this but issue is it was leading to another exception
`Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan"
`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I have not yet added answer here I was able to achieve what I wanted. I will add the approach I took and other possible solution today

Answer (score 0):

after trying several appproaches I found two that worked

1. remove cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true and use CascadeType.Merge, CascadeType.Persist, i.e not use CascadeType.Detach

Issue with this approach is that I have been using this feature when trying to remove parent entity during update and delete, and I also wanted to make sure that a child if removed from the set of children. In all I was breaking my already existing APIs for new API

2. Instead, a cleaner, yet simple approach. I used BeanUtils.copy to simply copy the fields and then separately copying the children properties too and then use the newly created Children which had no relation with existing entities.

```
  Set<AlertDetail> allByOrgId =
        allForMasterOrg.stream()
            .map(
                alertDetail -> {
                  final AlertDetail copy = new AlertDetail();
                  BeanUtils.copyProperties(alertDetail, copy);
                  copy.setId(0L);
                  copy.setOrgId(orgId);
                  copy.setDataEventMetadata(
                      alertDetail.getDataEventMetadata().stream()
                          .map(
                              alertDataEventMetadata -> {
                                final AlertDataEventMetadata copyMeta =
                                    new AlertDataEventMetadata();
                                BeanUtils.copyProperties(alertDataEventMetadata, copyMeta);
                                return copyMeta;
                              })
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
                  return copy;
                })
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    alertDetailDAO.saveAll(allByOrgId);
```